# Check if any of the items in a list satisfy a condition

Tags: c#

I have a list of 11 items as follows

```
List<string> telcos = new List<string> { "024", "054", "055", "027", "057", "020", "050", "026", "056", "023", "028" };
```

Now I am trying to compare from the list items to see if at least one of the items is equal to the strings I am comparing with.
If any one of the items is equal to my string comparison, the loop should stop but I am getting a repeated loop which is giving me an error.

```
foreach (string fonItem in telcos)
{
   if (frm["txtPhoneNumberField"].Substring(0, 3) != fonItem)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < loopFoneCount; i++)
       {
           listOfPhonesEdit.Add(frm["PhoneNumberTextBox" + i]);
           ViewBag.ListOfPhonesEdit = listOfPhonesEdit;
       }

      this.redisplay();
      return View(customerModel);
   }
```

}

I need you help.

Comment: *"Check if any of the items in a list satisfy a condition"* --> [Linq Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your question is unclear. It seems that you want to return a ViewBag with all the PhoneNUmberTextBox is the prefix in txtPhoneNumber field is listed in telcos? Is that your objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but, if your objective is to add a series of *PhoneNumberTextBox* if the prefix present in *frm["txtPhoneNumberField"]* matches one of the prefixes listed in your *telcos* list, then you could write:

```
// Extract the prefix once and for all.....
string prefix = frm["txtPhoneNumberField"].Substring(0, 3) 

// Is the prefix listed in telcos?
if(telcos.Any(x => x==prefix)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < loopFoneCount; i++)
        listOfPhonesEdit.Add(frm["PhoneNumberTextBox" + i]);

     // This should be outside the for loop otherwise you get only the 
     // last number in frm....
     ViewBag.ListOfPhonesEdit = listOfPhonesEdit;

     // I am uncertain if these two lines should be inside the if or not.
     this.redisplay();
     return View(customerModel);
}
....
```

Comment: Steve, thanks for your answer. What I really want is that, I am comparing some values which is sent from my form on post to the controller. Because I am using foreach loop to iterate through the telcos list items, it keeps looping even when it found a match. I want the loop to exist if there is a match found.

Comment: _Any_ stops its internal loop when it finds a match (or better when the lambda expression returns true on the current element of the sequence)

Comment: Steve thanks a lot. Your idea is great and working for me. I should have thought closer than far. Another challenge also is that like the first example you gave, I want now to compare a list of List<string>tempTelcos = new List<string>(), tempTelcos.Add(frm["PhoneNumberTextBox" + i]) to the telcos list